# dynamically update d3js linegraph with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dynamic, linegraph

I'm trying to figure out, how to dynamically update that linegraph with new data, moving the graph to the left and adding new data from right - you get it? the usual behaviour as you see in https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Actually I am a beginner in d3 (javascript) and want to use external JSON data.

```
[
{"Values": ["1.59"], "Datetime": "2016-12-10 14:29:22.007"},
 {...}
{"Values": ["1.91"], "Datetime": "2016-12-10 14:29:23.230"},
 {...}
{"Values": ["0.52"], "Datetime": "2016-12-10 14:29:23.238"}
]
```

What I found on the web are examples of generated data or updating one file with another.

Maybe there is a solution for my problem by handling just one json datafile and manage to work with it by array methods?

Appreciate your help folks!

```
d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1814gv", function (error, data) {
if (error) throw error;
// format the data
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.Datetime = parseTime(d.Datetime);
    d.Values = +d.Values;

});
...
```

[Full-Code-Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pablues/zse58g8a/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is a bit vague, it sounds like you need to dig into the fundamentals of D3 a bit more to understand how data binding works.

There is an update pattern as shown in this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). When an array has elements added/updated/removed, then the related bound elements are added/updated/removed in the svg.

D3 uses the index of the array to decide where to add or update data by default, so if you want new data at the end of a line graph, you add it to the end of the array. If that is what you mean by transition to the right?

If you mean transition as visually changing from state to another, there is an example of this in the code you posted. The tooltip goes from opacity of 0 to 1 when a point is moused over.

The convention here is to mark an answer as correct if it solved, or you can upvote a helpful answer. Im not sure anyone will be able to answer your question as it is too broad

Comment: Updated my initial post with additional information about what I mean. It is not about the tooltip.

Comment: @Pablues as per the link you provided, you need to push a new element to the end of the array via push() and remove the first element from the front with shift() . The translation of the path makes it shift to the left. Then as each new element of data comes, this is executed to repeatedly shift the line. The axis needs to be done separately. Its quite advanced to do this, you need to understand the update pattern as I linked to and look at a tutorial for making a graph to understand to put it all together

Comment: look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/weERBj , it is randomly generated data, but the implementation should be similar for you. with d3.json your json becomes an array, so how you handle that array is your decision. in order to shift the line, you must be adding a new element to the end of the array that is bound to your path, and taking the first element away